# Powershell regex to match string except first one

Tags: html, regex, powershell, match

I have following html patterns.

```
href="{{url}}" class="item-name prdctNm">{{name}}</a><div>
href="/drugs/sporanox-100-mg-33294" class="item-name prdctNm">Sporanox (100 Mg)</a>
href="/drugs/sporan-200-mg-34240" class="item-name prdctNm">Sporan (200 Mg)</a>
href="/drugs/spornid-500-mg-25051" class="item-name prdctNm">Spornid (500 Mg)</a>
```

What I want is to get name of products like

> `Sporanox (100mg), Sporan (200 mg) and Spornid (50mg).`

**

> Updated Solution

** : it matches almost whole of page. Starting from `first instance of` `"item-name prdctNm"` to `last <\a>` on page - it matches everything in between. However, I need to match `text between "item-name prdctNm" and tag <\a>` next to it.

Now it works perfectly :

```
$regex = [RegEx]'"item-name prdctNm"(.[^{}<>]*)</a>'
$url = ‘https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=sporanox’
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$content = $wc.DownloadString($url)
$regex.Matches($content) | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then print the group index 1 at the last where `Groups[0]` contains the entire match and `Groups[1]` contains the characters which are captured by the first group.

```
$regex = [RegEx]'"item-name prdctNm">([^}{<>]*)</a>'
$url = ‘https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=sporanox’
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$content = $wc.DownloadString($url)
$regex.Matches($content) | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: Thanks so this works if I include '<>' in RegEX. Is there any way - I can instruct my RegEX to match upto first </a>. Hope you understood my question.

Comment: simple, use non-greedy or reluctant quantifier `?` next to `*`... `[RegEx]'"item-name prdctNm">(.*?)</a>'`

Comment: @Yogesh ask it as a seperate question. I don't know much more about powershell.